# Django external documenaton access in Pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm

Some time ago I've found a site on the web that redirected to Django official documentation by symbol so that it could be used in Pycharm to open up browser by pressing `Shift+F1` on something. It was very convenient. I've lost it at some point and cannot find it again.

So I need URL for Django external docs in Pycharm.